# My screen's colors are inverted? or maybe reduced to only 8 different color?

Tags: screen

My screen's color on Ubuntu is totally inverted as shown in this image

[image]

I don't know why it does that, but it occurs at startup of the OS, everything goes from normal colors to kind of inverted colors. I've also tried `xcalib -i -a` which give me the following : `Error - Can't open display`

UPDATE : Ok it seems that there is only 8 different color available, i found a program that shows me the colors in the 256-color palette along with their ANSI color code in XTerm/ANSI-compatible terminals with a 256-color palette support. [image]

UPDATE 2 : Ok I've managed to fix this problem, i don't really know how but i tried install all package that is required by my graphic card AMD Radeon HD 7450 and also package of Mesa3D without really installing them, i probably needed their libs to fix that problems.

Comment: Do things work properly with a Live USB?

Comment: @DKBose No it doesn't, By the way i've got a Radeon HD 7450 as a graphic card. I'm trying to see if there is any driver problem or anything like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### quick answer:

install the required drivers manually. I'm answering for people that might run into this sometime, I ran into it today and fixed it this way.

### detailed answer and resources

I use Ubuntu Server 18.04 here. The drivers are avalable at [AMDs support site](https://www.amd.com/en/support).
Download them (all 4 files are necessary, there are some useful hints in [the installation guide](https://drivers.amd.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf) provided by AMD) for your OS. In my case the most recent ones seemed to be for Ubuntu 14.04, nevertheless they worked.

After downloading them on a separate machine (wget didn't work on the server) I copied them to some local folder of my default user on the server, installed the required dependencies, then installed the 4 .deb packages from AMD and rebooted my server.